# Discord Votemute Bot

Tags: discord

it is invalid and I dont know how to fix it (it is for a Discord Votemute Bot).

```
if(!msg.mentions.users.first()) return msg.channel.send('You need to mention somebody!'); // Check if no User was Mentioned
const voting = new Discord.RichEmbed() // Generate Voting Embed
    .setColor('#42b34d')
    .setFooter('Mute ' + msg.mentions.users.first().tag + ' for 10m?')
    .setImage(msg.mentions.users.first().avatarURL);
const role = msg.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Muted'); // Find Role
if(!role) return msg.channel.send('No Role was found, please make sure you have a muteed role!'); // Make sure there is a Role
const agree = '✅'; // Define Emojis
const disagree = '❌'; // Define Emojis

const sentEmbed = await msg.channel.send(voting); // Send Embed
const filter = (reaction, user) => (reaction.emoji.name === agree || reaction.emoji.name === disagree) && !user.bot; // Filter for Reactions
await sentEmbed.react(agree); // React
await sentEmbed.react(disagree); // React
const voteStatus = await msg.channel.send('Voting started 30 seconds left'); // Send start Message and
const collected = await sentEmbed.awaitReactions(filter, { time: 5000 }); // start Collecting Reactions
const agreed = collected.get(agree) || { count: 1 }; // Retrieve Reactions
const disagreed = collected.get(disagree) || { count : 1 }; // Retrieve Reactions
const agreed_count = agreed.count - 1 ; // Count away Bot Votes
const disagreed_count = disagreed.count - 1; // Count away Bot Votes
voteStatus.edit('Voting endet with: ' + agreed_count + agree + ' and ' + disagreed_count + disagree); // Edit message to show Outcome
if(agreed.count > disagreed.count) {
    await msg.guild.member(msg.mentions.users.first()).addRole(role);
    await wait(600000);
    await msg.guild.member(msg.mentions.users.first()).removeRole(role);
}
else {
    msg.channel.send('Mute Voting Failed :)');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For reasons I could not pinpoint, `msg.guild.member(msg.mentions.users.first())` returns null. The way I managed to get the guild member from the mention is with:

```
msg.guild.fetchMember(msg.mentions.users.first())
.then(async member => {
    ...
});
```

Furthermore, there is no `wait` function I'm aware of in js, so I replaced that as well, leaving your code looking like this:

```
msg.guild.fetchMember(msg.mentions.users.first())
.then(async member => {
  await member.addRole(role);
  setTimeout(function () { member.removeRole(role); }, 600000);
});
```